# How do I handle this dbnull exception properly?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

This error only happens when there is no user specified in the database. I have no idea why is this happening. I thought I handled the exception, but apparently, not.

The dbnull handling was fine until I made changes to the code and stored procedure where the error returns again.

I've tried , but it isn't working as well.

```
   if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(cmd.ExecuteScalar()))
                        {
                         userId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                        }
```

error type

```
Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

Source Error: 



Line 31:                     try
Line 32:                     {
Line 33:                         userid = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
Line 34:                     }
Line 35:                     catch (SqlException sqlEx)



[InvalidCastException: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.]
   System.DBNull.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider) +52
   System.Convert.ToInt32(Object value) +30
   clockin.RegisterUser(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\na3307\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\clockin.aspx.cs:33
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9782698
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +204
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1639
```

aspx

```
   protected void RegisterUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int userid = 0;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("clocking"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    Session["username"] = txtUsername.Text;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text.Trim());
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString());
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();

                    try
                    {
                        userid = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                    }
                    catch (SqlException sqlEx)
                    {
                        if (sqlEx.Message.StartsWith("dbnull name "))
                        {
                            Label1.Text = "DBnull";
                        }                        
                        else
                            throw;
                    }



                    string message = string.Empty;


                    switch (userid)
                    {
                        case -1:
                            message = "You have already clocked in, TRY AGAIN LATER";
                            Label1.Text = message;

                            break;
                        case -2:
                            message = "Not ready to clock in yet OR User not registered!";
                            Label1.Text = message;
                            break;
                        default:
                            message = txtUsername.Text + ", You have clocked in successfully.";
                            Label1.Text = message;
                            break;

                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[clocking]
      @Username NVARCHAR(100),
     @b nvarchar(100)

AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

            SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() -- UserId     
     IF EXISTS(select createddate,count(*) from clockin  where username = @Username and eventname = @b
group by createddate
HAVING COUNT(createddate) = 1
)
BEGIN
  SELECT -1 -- Username exists.
                  
END
         
      ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT userid FROM selected WHERE Username = @Username and datepart(hour, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN (select timein from timing) and (select timeout from timing) and
eventname = @b)

      BEGIN
                 INSERT INTO [clockin]
                     ([Username]
                     ,[CreatedDate],
                      [time],
                      [eventname]

)
            VALUES
                     (@Username                    
                    ,GETDATE(),
                     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                     @b
)
      END          

  ELSE IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT userid FROM selected WHERE Username = @Username and eventname = @b)

BEGIN
  SELECT -2 -- Not ready to clock in yet OR User not registered!
                  
END
        
 
BEGIN
    update selected
set times =
(select count (*) from clockin
where selected.username = clockin.username)

END

END
```

Comment: Your question is messy, please spend a few minutes making it more readable if you want people to help you. With that said, it looks like you are calling the procedure two times. The first time you call it, it returns a value, the second time it doesn't.

Comment: I have solved it, thanks. Wasn't sure what the root cause is, so I posted everything.


Placing     `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() -- UserId` at the bottom of the stored procedure solved this